# Change font size globally on GUI label

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to change the font size globally on my GUI labels but it give me an error:

> MissingFieldException: UnityEngine.GUIStyle.fonSize
>       Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.PropertyDispatcherFactory.FindExtension 
>       (IEnumerable`1 candidates)

This is my code

```
static var myScore = 0;
static var score = 0;
static var money = 0;
static var level = 0;
static var drinks = 0;
var fontSize  : int = 20;

public var guiSkin : GUISkin;

function OnGUI()
{
  GUI.skin = guiSkin;

  GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
  GUI.skin.label.fontSize = fontSize;
  GUI.Label(Rect((Screen.width / 2) - 60,15, 200, 30), "Score: " + score);
  GUI.Label(Rect((Screen.width / 2) - 60,30, 200, 30), "Money: " + money);
  GUI.Label(Rect((Screen.width / 2) - 60,42, 200, 30), "Level: " + level);
  GUI.Label(Rect((Screen.width / 2) - -320,25, 200, 30), "Drinks: " + drinks);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are following some old tutorial. I suggest you stop because you are using old GUI system that will be removed in the future. Avoid anything that requires the `OnGUI` function unless it for Editor plugin.

You should be using Unity's new UI system. In this case you need the [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) component and you can change the font size with the [`Text.font`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-font.html) variable. See [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) for full UI tutorial in Unity.